# In Javascript, how to find a character in a string and put all the characters before it in a variable

Tags: javascript

In javascript, I am trying to make a program that had to do with fractions that you can input and I need a function that will convert a fraction in this format( "10/27") to either 10 or 27 depending on user specification but I don't know how I would code this function. Any code or suggestions to get me started would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string into an array with `split()`, then take the first or second part as the numerator or denominator:

```
function getNumerator(fraction) {
    // fraction = "10/27"
    return fraction.split("/")[0];
}

function getDenominator(fraction) {
    // fraction = "10/27"
    return fraction.split("/")[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search in string using `indexOf()`. It returns first position of searched string.

If you want to split string using a character in it, use `split()`. It will return an array. So for eg: in you string *27/10*, indexOf */* is *3* but if you do split, you will get array of 2 values, 27 and 10.

```js
function splitString(str, searchStr) {
  return str.split(searchStr);
}

function calculateValue(str) {
  var searchStr = '/';
  var values = splitString(str, searchStr);
  var result = parseInt(values[0]) / parseInt(values[1]);
  notify(str, result);
}

function notify(str, result) {
  console.log(result);
  document.getElementById("lblExpression").innerText = str;
  document.getElementById("lblResult").innerText = result;

}

(function() {
  var str = "27/10";
  calculateValue(str)
})()
```

```html
Expression:
<p id="lblExpression"></p>
Result:
<p id="lblResult"></p>
```

Comment: Could you put it in a function?

Answer (score 0):

```
var fraction = "10/27".split("/");
var numerator = fraction[0];
var denominator = fraction[1];
```

You can of course use a library for it too: https://github.com/ekg/fraction.js

With this library the answer would be:

```
(new Fraction(10, 27)).numerator
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering `str` contains the input value then,

```
a = str.substring(str.indexOf("/")+1);
b = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("/"));
```

**Output:**
if str is `"10/17"` then,

```
a == 17;
b == 10;
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not test it before. Now it is working perfectly.